# Can you remotely control Lego Education WeDo 2.0 creations using the WeDo app?

Tags: remote-control, wedo

I wonder if the WeDo 2.0 app has remote control capabilities or is it only about programming the creations and then running the programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, no.

I've seen a few videos about Lego Wedo 2.0, and from what I can tell, it doesn't have it. One video shows a few of the models and some of the user's programs, but he doesn't mention even a *virtual* remote control and if it existed he would've because it's an obvious key feature for robotics. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GXHxmNsk1o) was made without the official app and I bet that its creator wouldn't have bothered making it if the official app already had the option to make remote control.

Lego Boost, Control+, PoweredUp, and EV3 have virtual remote control though.

<sup>I found [an intresting "remote control"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgxhQfex5CQ).</sup>